# Is libsnappy.so and its variants needed?

Tags: apt, snap, ubuntu-core

My Ubuntu 16.04 has `libsnappy.so.*` files in `/usr/lib/i386...` folders.

- Do I need them?

Also, there is a `/usr/lib/snapd.glib` folder even after I removed snap.

- Can I just purge all remnants of snap, snapd and snappy related files with brute force?
- Is there a way to remove them intelligently without leaving residues?

I already did `apt autoremove` and `apt autoclean` yet these are still here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These libraries (`libsnappy.so.*`) are contained in the following packages:

```
$ dpkg -S libsnappy.so
libsnappy1v5:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsnappy.so.1.3.0
libsnappy1v5:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsnappy.so.1

$ apt-file search libsnappy.so
libsnappy-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsnappy.so
libsnappy1v5: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsnappy.so.1
libsnappy1v5: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsnappy.so.1.3.0
```

According to dependencies they are needed on my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS system because of the following reverse dependencies:

```
$ apt-cache rdepends libsnappy1v5
libsnappy1v5
Reverse Depends:
  libsnappy-dev
  libavcodec-ffmpeg56
  libavcodec-ffmpeg-extra56
  juju-mongodb3.2
  ceph-test
  ceph
  python3-tables-lib
  python3-tables-dbg
  python-tables-lib
  python-tables-dbg
  python-snappy
  mongodb-server
  mongodb-clients
  libwiredtiger0
  libsnappy-jni
  libshogun16
  librocksdb4.1
  libmtbl0
  libblosc1
  libavcodec-ffmpeg56
  libavcodec-ffmpeg-extra56
  juju-mongodb3.2
  juju-mongodb2.6
  juju-mongodb
  ceph-test
  boomaga
  apitrace-gui
  apitrace
  androguard
  ceph
  libleveldb1v5
```

They are used by the following installed packages:

```
$ apt-cache rdepends --installed libsnappy1v5 
libsnappy1v5
Reverse Depends:
  libavcodec-ffmpeg-extra56
  python3-tables-lib
  python-tables-lib
  libavcodec-ffmpeg-extra56
```

So on my system I can't remove `libsnappy1v5` package.

Answer (score 2):

`snapd` and `snappy` are two different things.

snappy is [compression used by hadoop](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-9-x/topics/introduction_compression_snappy.html)

[Wikipedia Snappy compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snappy_(compression))

> Snappy (previously known as Zippy) is a fast data compression and
>   decompression library written in C++ by Google based on ideas from
>   LZ77 and open-sourced in 2011.[2](https://docs.snapcraft.io/core/snapd) It does not aim for maximum
>   compression, or compatibility with any other compression library;
>   instead, it aims for very high speeds and reasonable compression.
>   Compression speed is 250 MB/s and decompression speed is 500 MB/s
>   using a single core of a Core i7[which?] processor running in 64-bit
>   mode. The compression ratio is 20–100% lower than gzip.

[snapd](https://docs.snapcraft.io/core/snapd) - [what is snap](https://docs.snapcraft.io/snaps/intro)

> - is a squashFS filesystem containing your app code and a snap.yaml file containing specific metadata. It has a read-only file-system and,
>     once installed, a writable area.
> - is self-contained. It bundles most of the libraries and runtimes it needs and can be updated and reverted without affecting the rest of
>     the system.
> - is confined from the OS and other apps through security mechanisms, but can exchange content and functions with other snaps according to
>     fine-grained policies controlled by the user and the OS defaults.

Comment: I thought I removed snap, but `snapd.glib` is still there. Why?